# Easy sample of Google Maps API not working with Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, amp-html

I'm trying to implement this easy 'Hello World' sample with the Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP) technology.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      #map {height: 100%;}
      html, body {height: 100%;margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},zoom: 8});}
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=foo&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works ok, but if I insert the AMP libraries as the second child of the  tag

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
```

it stops working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that only the [`amp-iframe`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/layout/amp-iframe) is the only possible way to embed a map in an AMP supported page.

Here is the [example](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/author-develop/iframes) on how to use amp-iframe in embedding a map.

```
<amp-iframe width=300 height=300
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"
    layout="responsive"
    frameborder="0"
    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyDG9YXIhKBhqclZizcSzJ0ROiE0qgVfwzI&q=Alameda,%20CA">
</amp-iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use a Google-Maps-Embed-API iframe within a regular HTML page, it works. But if I use the same 'src' with the code you provided, it does not. I created the 'Hello World' AMP sample, I added the code you provided (with my own key), it's AMP-validated, but ellipsis appear and the map is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing amp html tag [`<html amp lang="en">`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create/basic_markup)
2. You're missing amp boilerplate code
3. Your css should be inside `<amp-style></style>`tag
4. AMP doesn't allow user-generated scripts, so your script `initMap()` is non-compliant
5. If you want to embed a map, you should put it inside `<amp-iframe>` tag. [Like this](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/):

```html
<amp-iframe width="600"
  height="400"
  layout="responsive"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups"
  frameborder="0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA&key=AIzaSyCNCZ0Twm_HFRaZ5i-FuPDYs3rLwm4_848">
</amp-iframe>
```